# Why won't my Datamaps plugin show up on my Tumblr blog page?

Tags: maps, tumblr, datamaps

Trying to install datamaps plugin onto Tumblr blog page, map won't show up

I'm a beginner to coding, and have been trying to install an interactive political on a page of my tumblr; I have received permission from Support to run Javascript on my blog. I've been following the documentation on the Github and put the following code on page:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
<script>
    var map = new Datamap({element: document.getElementById('container')});
</script>
```

However, nothing shows up when I hit the preview button. Using inspect, the container is present but the map is not.

Comment: What is your blog? I think there will be an error in the console because you are calling `<script src="/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>` where it should be `<script src="//datamaps.world.min.js"></script>` two '//' before the url. Also there needs to be an element in the markup with the id container.

Comment: LOL, now I see the container ID as you are creating it just before the script